# ReactJs - Passing an array from parent component to child component

Tags: reactjs, components

I've a stateless component called `Gender` that I'm calling in the parent class component `App` and I want to pass in the `users` array so that I can filter the array to count the number of males and females in the component `Gender`.

```
let Gender = (mCount, fCount) => {
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Male</span>
            <span>{mCount}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Females</span>
            <span>{fCount}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ users: data }));
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
        <div classname="wrapper">
            <Gender />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass as regularly with props:

```
 <Gender users={users} />
```

And update your `Gender` component:

```
const Gender = (mCount, fCount, users) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Male</span>
            <span>{mCount}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Females</span>
            <span>{fCount}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it works but any specific reason for using `users` as an attribute?

Comment: Well, the array is called `users`.

Comment: so the attribute name should be same as it's value?

Comment: No, the attribute name doesn't matter.